# How can I recover Linux partition which is mistakenly had fdisk run on it

Tags: fdisk, testdisk

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 system with two disk (`/dev/sda1` `/dev/sdb1`).

`/dev/sdb1` is in ext4 format before.

Someone ran the following command with default options:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb1
```

How can I recover this partition?

I have tried to run testdisk but don't know how to use.

Comment: Running fdisk won't do anything else than open fdisk command prompt...

Answer (score 0):

Since I have not erased anything but just remove ext4 signature. `fsck /dev/sdb1` will recover the partition.